# using c#, how can I execute a tsql user-function and get its returned value?

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following tsql function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_MyFunc] (
        @AccountId varchar(50)
)
returns bit
as 
begin 

    declare @IsEligible bit
        --some calculation
    return @IsEligible


end
```

Using c#, is that the way to call this tsql function and get its returned value?

```
     Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DB");
     using (DbCommand dbCommand = database.GetStoredProcCommand("fn_MyFunc"))
                    {
                        database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@AccountId", DbType.String, "1234");
 bool returnedVAlue = (bool)dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Surely you can test whether that is the way to call the function? What happens when you run that code - if you get the right result then it is, if you get an exception then it isn't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are calling a function you would have to call it using inline sql rather than a stored procedure. So rather than calling a stored proc you would call

```
select dbo.fn_myFunc(?) as result
```

You could also create a stored procedure that just wraps up the call to the function.

Comment: my bad, thought it was simple enough it didn't need it - it does look loads better for it however!

Comment: You might find it easier to create a stored procedure that just calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way if you're using the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block

Comment: he's calling a function not a stored procedure. That code shouldn't work.